# Differencing a perfectly seasonal time series

Tags: time-series, forecasting

I was just playing around today with differencing and wanted to see what happened if I differenced a sine function. As far as I am aware, differencing usually results in producing small auto correlations.

My expectation was that differencing a perfectly seasonal function would result in near 0 ACFs. What happened was that my ACFs were just as large as the sine function ACFs.

To set this up I used the following code:

```
library(tidyverse)

#prepare data
df <- as_tibble(list(x = seq(0, 8*2*pi, length.out = 5000))) %>% 
  mutate(y = sin(x),
         diff = c(NA, diff(y)),
         date = seq(as_date("2010-01-01"), by = "1 day", length.out = 5000))

df %>% ggplot(aes(y = y, x = date))+
  geom_line() +
  geom_line(aes(y = diff))
```

[image]

Code for the ACFs:

```
library(tsibblestats)
df %>% 
  na.omit() %>% 
  ACF(value = diff)

     lag   acf
   <lag> <dbl>
 1  1DAY 1.000
 2  2DAY 0.999
 3  3DAY 0.998
 4  4DAY 0.998
 5  5DAY 0.997
 6  6DAY 0.996
 7  7DAY 0.995
 8  8DAY 0.994
 9  9DAY 0.992
10 10DAY 0.991
```

and sine acf

```
df %>% 
  na.omit() %>% 
  ACF(value = y)
     lag   acf
   <lag> <dbl>
 1  1DAY 1.000
 2  2DAY 1.000
 3  3DAY 1.000
 4  4DAY 0.999
 5  5DAY 0.999
 6  6DAY 0.998
 7  7DAY 0.998
 8  8DAY 0.997
 9  9DAY 0.996
10 10DAY 0.995
```

If differencing is supposed to make a seasonal time series stationary, why is this not the case in a perfectly seasonal time series, as shown with the sine function?

Comment: @StephanKolassa Thanks for pointing out the error in my code, and pronving the insignificant ACFs.

Comment: @StephanKolassa I agree that the code is not particularly straightforward, but the question is clearly about `y=sin(x)` and `diff(y)`, neither of which is stationary, and not about `x` (that `seq` expression) or `diff(x)`.

Comment: @ChrisHaug: thanks! I completely forgot including a `sin()`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Differencing does not necessarily make a process stationary. It works when your data is a stationary process that has been integrated. In that case, taking the difference will invert that operation and return the original stationary process. Otherwise, you should not expect it to work.

In the case of a deterministic sine process, if the period of the sine is an integer number of steps (say, $k$), then the difference at that lag ($z_t = y_t - y_{t-k}$) will give you a stationary process. This is obvious from the fact that the periodicity will make that difference zero at all times.

For your specific example, the minor tweak:

```
x = seq(0, 8*2*pi, length.out = 5000 + 1)
```

will mean that the period is exactly 5000/8 = 625, and therefore the difference $y_t - y_{t-625} = 0$ is stationary. If you try it in software you will probably not get exactly zero at all times and you may get some residual autocorrelation; this is due to finite precision arithmetic.